# Is it good practice for tests in a test case depend on each other?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, testcase

I have a class that I would like to test:

```
class DocumentProcessor{

  public function write(){

  }

  public function read(){

  }
}
```

And I have a simple test case:

```
class ClientTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testWrite(){

    }

    public function testRead(){

    }
}
```

In this case, can `testRead()` depend on data `testWrite()` has written? Or is it better practice to have `testRead()` setup its own data and read from it? The latter approach does seem to be a bit more repetitive, but one can test `testRead()` on its own.

Answer (score 1):

I think having both types is beneficial. The tests can be much more fine-grained when written independently, each testing interesting normal and edge cases, etc. However, it's always good to have an integration test verifying that the reader can read what the writer writes. This is especially helpful when the format of the output changes (and it always does) to make sure both the reader and writer get updated.

Testing `read()` independently might also be required if you have to support reading old/legacy-formatted input that the `write()` method no longer produces.

Answer (score 0):

Tests are best when independent, or at least tested in a bottom up approach. You can test testWrite using testRead as long as you have shown that testRead works independently of testWrite (and so on).

Answer (score 0):

A big Test Case/Suite can take time to execute. For this reason, usually test engineers try to avoid redundancy. For example, they usually avoid to test get/set methods because they are used in other tests.

But I'm only reporting a common practice - personally, I don't have a strong opinion about this topic.